# Iterating array in complex way in reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json

Response JSON:

```
[
    [{
            "name": "IMG00177.png",
            "class": "Pore",
            "confidence": "0.9",
            "bbox": [160.0, 916.0, 169.0, 925.0],
            "segmentation": []
        },
        {
            "name": "IMG00177.png",
            "class": "Pore",
            "confidence": "0.81",
            "bbox": [107.0, 890.0, 112.0, 896.0],
            "segmentation": []
        },
        {
            "name": "IMG00177.png",
            "class": "Pore",
            "confidence": "0.57",
            "bbox": [119.0, 871.0, 123.0, 873.0],
            "segmentation": []
        },
        {
            "name": "IMG00177.png",
            "class": "Pore",
            "confidence": "0.63",
            "bbox": [343.0, 703.0, 346.0, 705.0],
            "segmentation": []
        },
        {
            "name": "IMG00177.png",
            "class": "Pore",
            "confidence": "0.9",
            "bbox": [337.0, 692.0, 345.0, 701.0],
            "segmentation": []
        }
    ],
    [{
            "name": "IMG00178.png",
            "class": "Pore",
            "confidence": "0.53",
            "bbox": [1183.0, 1078.0, 1185.0, 1081.0],
            "segmentation": []
        },
        {
            "name": "IMG00178.png",
            "class": "Pore",
            "confidence": "0.83",
            "bbox": [155.0, 1002.0, 161.0, 1008.0],
            "segmentation": []
        },
        {
            "name": "IMG00178.png",
            "class": "Pore",
            "confidence": "0.72",
            "bbox": [107.0, 891.0, 111.0, 893.0],
            "segmentation": []
        },
        {
            "name": "IMG00178.png",
            "class": "Pore",
            "confidence": "0.77",
            "bbox": [121.0, 871.0, 126.0, 873.0],
            "segmentation": []
        }
    ]
]
```

This is the response array for my api post request. i have a empty array and i want to check if the image name is same for another list. i want to parse that bbox value in list.
Needed format:

```
[
{
"name":"1.png",
"confidence":[[0.9],[0.9],[0.9],[0.9],[0.9]],
"bbox":[[160.0, 916.0, 169.0, 925.0],[107.0, 890.0, 112.0, 896.0],[119.0, 871.0, 123.0, 873.0],[343.0, 703.0, 346.0, 705.0]]

}
]
```

I didn't have a clue how to iterate over this to get the required format.kindly guide me to approach this problem

Comment: OP: _i have a empty array_. Okay, so, there is an empty array. Noted. Now,  _i want to check if the image name is same for another list_ <-- where is this _image name_, and where is this _another list_, could you please share those inputs as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code to get the required output. I have written captured each manipulation of the response in a separate variable for better understanding, but feel free to refactor to lesser lines of code. Do let me know if it fulfills your requirement.

```
const flatArray = [].concat.apply([], response);

const flatMap = flatArray.reduce((accum, e) => {
  if (!accum[e.name]) {
    accum[e.name] = {
      name: e.name,
      bbox: [e.bbox],
      confidence: [[e.confidence]]
    };
  } else {
    accum[e.name].confidence.push([e.confidence]);
    accum[e.name].bbox.push(e.bbox);
  }
  return accum;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(flatMap));
```

Snapshot of the console.

[image]